# Certain CSS Not Loading In IE7 And IE8 When CSS Is Aggregated and Compressed

Tags: theming, css-js-aggregation

When enabling "Aggregate and compress CSS files" on Drupal 7.15, a few styles don't seem to load in IE7 and IE8. Two issues involve CSS3 Pie not working, and one involves regular styling. Because of this I don't think its a CSS3 Pie issue.

When I inspect one of the elements that is supposed to have a drop shadow, I can see the line `Behavior: url(../sites/all/themes/revo/PIE.htc);` is there. However it's not taking affect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- I am not using more than 31 style sheets
- I have tried the following in the settings.php file

  $conf['css_gzip_compression'] = FALSE;
  $conf['js_gzip_compression'] = FALSE;